# При попытке в c++ заполнить динамический массив VS2019 выдает "ошибку"

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, visual-studio-2019

При попытке заполнить массив (код ниже) Visual Studio выдает "ошибку".

```
int size = 7;

int *m = new int(size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

    m[i] = rand() % 10;

  }

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

    cout << m[i] << '\t';

    cout << m + i << endl;

}

delete[] m;
```

При запуске выходит след. сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это может быть?

Comment: `i < size - 1`.

Comment: При создании динамического массива размер указывается в квадратных скобках. `new int[size];`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, двойка. i < size, тут как раз всё правильно. Про [ ] уже написали.

Comment: Про ошибку уже ответили, но я очень сомневаюсь, что ошибка на скриншоте вообще вызвана этим кодом. Там адрес 4, который ника не может получиться выходом за границу массива, тем более интового. Скорее где-то null в указателе лежит. Хотя, g++ тоже что-то интересное намутил: https://ideone.com/lZ0GKp

Comment: Прикольно. cout себе тоже что-то от памяти хочет, так что если первый cout стоит после записи, то программа валится. А вот если до, то работает как надо: https://ideone.com/T9iLu8 :D Какое же прикольное UB.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня g++ ничего не намутил, всё скомпилировалось и запустилось. А ошибка в ntdll.dll - довольно частое явление при выполнении программы в отладчике. Я с этим иногда сталкивался, когда из IDA запускал под отладкой некоторые исследуемые мною программы. При обычном запуске - всё работает, под отладкой - вылет с ошибкой доступа в ntdll.dll. Не знаю, почему так. Предполагаю, что и в данном примере это сообщение так же с отладкой связано.

Comment: @LShadow77, меня просто адрес удивил - около нуля. А на ideone вообще валится malloc c повреждённой кучей.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *m = new int(size);
```

Вот тут Вы создаете в куче одну переменную типа int и присваиваете ей значение size.
Для создания массива, необходимо использовать квадратные скобки

```
int *m = new int[size];
```